# WooCommerce remove specific fee

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently adding a feee on checkout;

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_cart_total' );
function custom_cart_total($order_total) {
    WC()->cart->add_fee( __('Military Discount', 'woocommerce'), -$totalDiscount );
}
```

I have some additional conditional logic to add where I may want to remove this specific fee `Military Discount`. I don't see an option of `remove_fee`. I could 0 out the discount but then it will show on the invoice which I don't want if it is 0.

How can I remove this discount based on some of my stores logic?

Further details - 
I could only add the discount based on logic instead of removing it however, this WooCommerce store is unique in the fact the shopping is done in-store. We have issues where customers are getting the discount due to cache/cookies/ or sessions. So I'm looking to force clear all the discounts for the next user.

Comment: have you create add_fee field?

Comment: no? I just use the add_fee function which works perfectly for me. I'm just struggling to remove it in some instances

Comment: WC()->cart->add_fee( __('Military Discount', 'woocommerce'), -$totalDiscount ); this the add_fee functions?

Comment: Why not adding it depending on your conditional logic instead of adding it and removing it afterwards?

Comment: @Mr.Jo Yes that would be okay for some instances but my shop is unique. I've updated the question with additional information.

Comment: Why not clearing the whole cart instead? WC()->cart->empty_cart(); And maybe you should check that you'r cart don't get's cached because this would be very bad.

Comment: @Mr.Jo Because the add fee is on the`woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` hook which means on checkout your cart would be cleared. You would probably also have issues with customers returning to the site & their cart being cleared.

Comment: @SamXronn I'm also adding fees depending on some values and check at the same hook so I can't follow you. I hope you find someone who can.

Comment: No worries @Mr.Jo thanks for your help I was just hoping WooCommerce supported removing a specific fee